# Правильно ли написано или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Биотуалеты в нашем городе, это чудо чудное, диво дивное.

Answer (score 1):

По классическим правилам здесь должно быть тире перед связкой ЭТО между подлежащим и именнной частью сказуемого:

***Биотуалеты в нашем городе — это чудо чудное, диво дивное.***

Можно ли поставить запятую? Маловероятно, хотя надо смотреть контекст. Как определить такую грамматику, именительный темы? Но там тоже ставится тире, запятой, вероятно, не обойдешься.